# Best approach to make 1 file and create download per user

Tags: php, html

I have a sitemap.xml generator that works with the input of the user. Everything works like a charm it creates and makes the XML it gets submitted automatically to the search engines.

so to create the idea; 
1) on 1 page you write your url
2) on submit the generator file opens en you see the result after 5 seconds you get redirected an a download pop-up appears

all this works.

Now i was thinking it works with 1 user at the time (creates sitemap.xml).

But what if more users go at the same time then, then it goes all bad i guess.

What would be the best approach to generate more sitemap.xml at once for specified users

What i was thinking or using session(id) or on submit button to create a directory and then with file_put_contents copy all the files that need to be loaded

but the last idea gets in conflict with the redirect to download.php

does any have a simple but solid idea, dont think it wil hit the millions of people. But would suck if it goes wrong